# Get samaccount name using display name, filter is not recognized

Tags: powershell, csv, filter

I have a list of user's displaynames in a txt file and am trying to pull their associated samaccount name.

The error I am getting is Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized

This is what I have tried:

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\studentlookup.txt | ForEach {
   Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'" -Properties Name, SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName | Select Name,SamAccountName, City, co, DistinguishedName
} | Export-CSV -path C:\Temp\studentresult.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: DisplayName is a column in the csv?

Comment: Is `C:\Temp\studentlookup.txt` really a _CSV_ file? The `.txt` extension suggests plain-text content. If it is the latter and contains just usernames, each on its own line, use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv` and `$_` instead of `$($_.DisplayName)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was overthinking it and you were both right, I should have been using a csv file with the displayname header.  I appreciate your eyes on this!